# Check if any replacement done by `perl -i -pe`

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

In `GNU sed`, I can display the result of successful substitution of the search pattern. Simple example as the following:

```
echo -e "nginx.service\nmariadb.service\nphp-fpm.service" > something.conf;
sed -ri 's|(mariadb)(\.service)|postgresql-9.4\2|w sed-output.log' something.conf;
[[ -s sed-output.log ]] && echo "Pattern found and modified. $(cat sed-output.log)" || echo "Pattern not found.";
```

Because `sed` has limitation while dealing with multilines, I switched to `perl`.

```
echo -e "nginx.service\nmariadb.service\nphp-fpm.service" > something.conf;
perl -i -pe 's|(mariadb)(\.service)|postgresql-9.4\2|' something.conf;
```

The code above did the same like `sed`, but how can I get the `modified content` ("`postgresql-9.4.service`") into a file, or printed out?

Basically what I would like to achieve is, after the script has been executed, it tells me if it's successful (and what actually substituted) and if not, I'll display a message of what couldn't be found and replaced.

---

Edit:
Highlighted that I want to get (only-the-) `modified content`, which indicates that my script is successful. Because with `perl -i -pe 's/pattern/replace/' file`, I couldn't know if it return true or false. Of course I can simple do `grep -E "/pettern/"` to find out, but that's not the question.

Comment: `\2` should be `$2` in replacement expressions. `-w` will warn you about this error.

Comment: By the way, `s|mariadb(?=\.service)|postgresql-9.4|` is faster, though I doubt it will matter here.

Comment: Indeed $1 is suggested when I run script test with `-pWe`, just wanted to keep both script looks the same. Also a good example of Positive Lookahead usage, I learned something, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't as tidy in Perl because you have to open your log file explicitly, and for a one-liner that has to be in a `BEGIN` block. But Perl's `s///` returns the number of changes made, so you can test it for truth

Note also that `$2` is better than `\2` in Perl, as the latter represents a character with code point 2, or Unicode U+0002 *START OF TEXT*

```
perl -i -pe ' BEGIN { open F, ">perl-output.log" } print F $_ if s|(mariadb)(\.service)|postgresql-9.4$2| ' something.conf
```

Comment: The result is identical to `/w sed-output.log` in simple tests. It's the substitution of `sed` line of code, exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This code will throw an exit code equal to `0` when *replacement* is done:

```
$ perl -i -pe '$M += s|(mariadb)(\.service)|postgresql-9.4\2|;END{exit 1 unless $M>0}' something.conf
$ echo $?
0
```

When **NO** substitution is done, *return* code will be `1`:

```
$ perl -i -pe '$M += s|(maria)(\.service)|postgresql-9.4\2|;END{exit 1 unless $M>0}' something.conf
$ echo $?
1
```

From `Perl` [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END)

> An **END code block is executed** as late as possible, that is, after perl
>   has finished running the program and **just before the interpreter is
>   being exited, even if it is exiting as a result of a die() function**.
>   (But not if it's morphing into another program via exec, or being
>   blown out of the water by a signal--you have to trap that yourself (if
>   you can).) You may have multiple END blocks within a file--they will
>   execute in reverse order of definition; that is: last in, first out
>   (LIFO). END blocks are not executed when you run perl with the -c
>   switch, or if compilation fails.

Number of *replacements* returned from [`s` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

> `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer`
>
> Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern
>   with the replacement text and returns the number of substitutions
>   made.

Comment: As a contrast, @Borodin added a `BEGIN` code block which actually allows it to produce the same result as `/w sed-output.log`. Thank you for the inspirations.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output directly if you only print the substituted lines:

```
if [[ -z $(sed -n 's/mariadb\(\.service\)/postgresql-9.4\1/p' something.conf) ]]; then
    echo nope
fi
```